# PHP-FPM showing 34 worker process despite adjusting configuration

Tags: centos, nginx, vps, php-fpm, optimization

I recently [asked this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/611655/swap-memory-exhausting-server-even-site-has-small-visitors) and I [got an answer](https://serverfault.com/a/612112/229793) about how I should limit php-fpm from running 34 worker process, considering that I get on average 20 visits for one light website.

So, I configured PHP-FPM as shown in the answer, the problem is that, as soon as I finished configuring php-fpm, I saw a huge chunk of memory freed from my VPS server, and assumed the problem was fixed. But when I checked today, I found out that I was running out of memory again, and that PHP-FPM is still running 34 worker process, despite the configuration. It seems the configuration is not reliable, or something is wrong with PHP-FPM. Does this happen to everyone? or am I doing the configuration wrong?

Comment: Just in case this helps. My `pm.max_requests` is set to `500` I can't decide if this is too high, as the previous answer didn't shed light in this directive.

Comment: First, you should answer in your other question rather than creating a new one.
Second, could you update your question with the content of all your configuration files ( with the private part removed), i.e. Nginx conf, Php FPM conf, etc...